# Searching with MySQL or ElasticSearch

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I have few problems with table searching in 1M rows in MySQL InnoDB table.

From these 1M rows is 100k active (where can be searched by many parameters including fulltext and geo searching). MySQL indexes are ok, so queries runs under 300ms, but it's still bad I think. Worst are huge offsets - query can take few seconds.

I am thinking about using ElasticSearch. Could someone tell me if it's good for me?

In that case I must synchronize MySQL database with Elastic, but if it's worth it I try it.

Comment: Asking for software/hosting recommendations/reviews is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: If you index your data in Elasticsearch using GeoPoint or GeoShape you will get amazing performance for geospatial searches.

Comment: @Marc B I know, but I am not searching for software or hosting. I need help if one technology helps me with another technology problems.

Comment: I think the issue is it will be hard to give suggestions without knowing much about how your system currently works. 1 million rows shouldn't be an issue with mysql though. Maybe there's things you could do with your code base to optimize your database calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elasticsearch is the solution you need to improve search performances and to avoid offsets.

elasticsearch is built to perform full-text and geo-location searches whereas MySQL is built to store datas.

Depending on the framework you are using, you can easily push your datas from MySQL to elasticsearch http://blog.randywallace.com/blog/2013/08/27/pulling-a-large-mysql-table-into-elasticsearch/.